# PHP - How to dinamically add a virtual route

Tags: php, path, virtual

Hi everybody and thanks in advance for your help!
I'm building a php website without using any framework. The site will be  multilingual and the client want to add a virtual path for each country, for example: www.mysite.com/ar/ for Argentina, www.mysite.com/cl/ for Chile, and so on. Some languagues will be the same translation, but it has to have his own virtual path. The country will be selected by a select element in HTML, and it has to change the route dinamically.

I was surfing other solutions but they all talk about Rewrite rules in .htaccess, which it's a static solution, but I need something dynamics.

I hope I had explained myself, and you could help me.
Tks !!

**/*EDIT 06-02-17*/**

More details as suggested:

1. I have a table in MySQL with the country. Each record has a code, a name of the country and a virtualPath (is just a string, for example: Code > ARG, Name > Argentina, virtualPath > AR).
2. In the header of the page, i'm loading a country selector. The user select his country (for ex: Spain) and I want to reload the page, changing the URL to match the virtualPath of the country. For ex: www.mywebsite.com/ES/ or www.mywebsite.com/AR/ and so on.

Hope the detail clears things up! Thanks!!

Comment: You need to use Apache's rewrite rules to point any sub-paths (like `/ar/`) to your `index.php`, then parse the URL and do the rest of the processing. Mind you, this is not as trivial as it sounds, which is why you should really consider using a PHP framework. Some are very simple - they only do routing (matching URLs to code) and help you render views (the HTML being returned), and you do the rest. Check this out for some recommendations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363993/micro-framework-like-flask-or-sinatra-for-php

Comment: Htaccess allows you to fetch part of the url and use it as a variable (example, appending to the end of the string as a get request) so your script knows what to do with it, and algo masquerading it to look like it's own path. That's why most of that kind of stuff is done with rewrite rules.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the short answer, I'm short of time but I hope I can point you in the right direction.

Look into `REST API`;

write yourself a PHP script that can evaluate the URL and then load the appropriate data according to the URL, get the appropriate data or path to data from a database which is updated by the user/client.

Good luck :)